# Trying to automate a game with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a script, to automate my game.

First look my snippet demo to finding out how my games works.

I know this request is a bit confusing but please help

```js
var randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange();

function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {

  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

$(".btn").click(function() {
  var inp1 = $("#inp1");
  var Gem = $("#Gem");
  var $getRnd = $("#getRand");
  if (Number(inp1.val()) > Number(Gem.val())) {
    alert(" you don't have enough Gem");
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  $getRnd.val(randomNumberFromRange(0, 1000));
  if (Number($getRnd.val()) >= "500") {
    $("#win").css("display", "block");
    var sum = Number(inp1.val()) + Number(Gem.val());
    Gem.val(Number(sum));
    $("#lose").css("display", "none");

  } else if (Number($getRnd.val()) <= "499") {
    $("#lose").css("display", "block");
    var sub = Number(Gem.val()) - Number(inp1.val());
    Gem.val(Number(sub));
    $("#win").css("display", "none");

  }
});
```

```css
#nav {
  background-color: #1b354b;
  border: 2pt solid gold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#Left_button,
#Right_button {
  background-color: gold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5pt;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: larger;
}

#left_Box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff942, yellow);
  ;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#right_Box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 170px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#FFB75E, yellow);
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#inp1,
#Gem,
#getRand {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  color: #ff0d2f;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: large;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#lose {
  display: none;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#win {
  display: none;
  background-color: #64f26f;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Model</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <input id="Left_button" class="btn" type="button" value="Left">
    <input id="Right_button" class="btn" type="button" value="Right">

    <div id="Body">
      <div id="left_Box">
        <label><span style="font-size: large">Gem Chance : </span><input id="inp1" type="text" value="1"></label>

      </div>
      <div id="right_Box">
        <label><span style="font-size: large">Gems : </span><input id="Gem" type="text" value="1000"
                                                                       disabled></label><br>
        <label><span style="font-size: large">Number : </span><input id="getRand" type="text" value=""></label>
        <br>
        <i style="color: #1b354b"> win : higher than 499</i>
        <br>
        <i style="color: #1b354b"> lose : lower than 500</i>

        <div id="Place">
          <div id="lose">lose</div>
          <div id="win">win</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

we have important parameters here.

```
Gem Chance :
Gems :
```

I want to create a script to do

```
1 - click buttons by random(left & right) every 2 sec . (click)
2 - after losing 3 times (continuous) , change the Gem chance to X (X=2)
3 - click 
4 - if win => reset => change Gem chance to 1
 and start from part 1;
5 - if lose => change Gem chance to 1 
and click ;
if lose  = > change Gem chance to 2X 
click ;
if win :
reset => change Gem chance to 1 
and start from part 1
if lose :
change Gem chance to 1
click ;
if win : reset 
but ( after 3 losing changes the Gem chance to last lose value )
```

last example:

After we reached 3 consecutive losses
After each loss
The chance of a gem becomes 1. And click.
And again the chance of gem
It doubles and clicks.
This will happen until we win.

But if between losses
When the gem chance.
He gave us the victory over the number 1
All steps are performed from the beginning with the difference that
Since the chance of gem. It's doubling its last loss.

Comment: left and right button have no special function, its same thing

Comment: i want a automatic script, its not depended on buttons

Comment: Stack Overflow, despite the answer you've been given, is not a code-on-demand service. You've told us what you want, which is great. How about you do some research into how you'd do it (and [edit] your question with the results of that research)? Maybe try a few things. Break the project down into smaller tasks, try to get that working, then move on to the next. If you come up short on a particular task, show us what you've tried, and we can help. But writing something that will automate playing your game for you? Way too much to ask volunteers.

Answer (score 1):

I give you the code to begin to build what you want, its the routine which launch every 2 sec the function automate and click randomly on left or right button.

```js
var randomNumber = randomNumberFromRange();
//begin to automate
var timer = setInterval(automate, 2000);
var buts=[$("#Left_button"), $("#Right_button")];
var win = 0;
var loose = 0;
var loop = 0;

function automate(){
  
  var idx=randomNumberFromRange(0, 1);
  buts[idx].trigger("click");
  
  console.log("i click on " + buts[idx].attr("id"));
  console.log("i " + $("#Place div[style='display: block;']").attr('id'));

  $("#inp1").val("111");//sample to modify the value of Gem chance

  if(loop++ == 4)  clearInterval(timer);//stop call the function after some loop

}



    function randomNumberFromRange(min, max) {

        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    }

    $(".btn").click(function () {
        var inp1 = $("#inp1");
        var Gem = $("#Gem");
        var $getRnd = $("#getRand");
        if (Number(inp1.val()) > Number(Gem.val())) {
            alert(" you don't have enough Gem");
            e.preventDefault()
        }
        $getRnd.val(randomNumberFromRange(0, 1000));
        if (Number($getRnd.val()) >= "500") {
            $("#win").css("display", "block");
            var sum = Number(inp1.val()) + Number(Gem.val());
            Gem.val(Number(sum));
            $("#lose").css("display", "none");

        } else if (Number($getRnd.val()) <= "499") {
            $("#lose").css("display", "block");
            var sub = Number(Gem.val()) - Number(inp1.val());
            Gem.val(Number(sub));
            $("#win").css("display", "none");

        }
    });
```

```css
#nav {
            background-color: #1b354b;
            border: 2pt solid gold;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 800px;
            height: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;

        }

        #Left_button, #Right_button {
            background-color: gold;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 5pt;
            border: none;
            width: 100px;
            height: 30px;
            margin: 5px;
            font-size: larger;

        }

        #left_Box {
            width: 300px;
            height: 170px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(#fff942, yellow);;
            text-align: center;
            float: left;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        #right_Box {
            width: 500px;
            height: 170px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(#FFB75E, yellow);
            text-align: center;
            float: right;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        #inp1, #Gem, #getRand {
            text-align: center;
            width: 50px;
            color: #ff0d2f;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: large;
            margin-top: 10px;

        }

        #lose {
            display: none;
            background-color: red;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 15px;
        }

        #win {
            display: none;
            background-color: #64f26f;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 15px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Model</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>
<div id="nav">
    <input id="Left_button" class="btn" type="button" value="Left">
    <input id="Right_button" class="btn" type="button" value="Right">

    <div id="Body">
        <div id="left_Box">
            <label><span style="font-size: large">Gem Chance : </span><input id="inp1" type="text" value="1"></label>

        </div>
        <div id="right_Box">
            <label><span style="font-size: large">Gems : </span><input id="Gem" type="text" value="1000"
                                                                       disabled></label><br>
            <label><span style="font-size: large">Number : </span><input id="getRand" type="text" value=""></label>
            <br>
            <i style="color: #1b354b"> win : higher than 499</i>
            <br>
            <i style="color: #1b354b"> lose : lower than 500</i>

            <div id="Place">
                <div id="lose">lose</div>
                <div id="win">win</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx . but this is not true firend . 
after 3 loses the gem chance shoud be 2 and click again , if lose ? gem chance =1 and click if lose ? gem chance =2x and click until win 
after each lose the script have to click with gem chance 1 and if win then reset , if lose gem chancce =1 after lose ? 2x until win 
ok?

Comment: @Alex they explained at the top `I give you the code to begin to build what you want`. You're asking for a lot in your question without appearing to have attempted it yourself first. @Frenchy is giving you a starting point, and you can build on top of this.

Comment: i tried , but i didnt get result , 
and the important point is here if i knew how to create  this , i didnt ask :)

Comment: Think through the logic of how you'd detect if you lose 3 times in a row. The simplest way is to have 3 separate variables keeping track of losses (`let lost1 = false;`, and set it to `true` once they lose once), and only set the next one (i.e. `lost2`) if the previous one is already `true`. On a win you can reset all of them. So if all 3 variables are `true`, you're at the point of 3 consecutive losses. Build from there - how would you change the X value in that instance? And keep track of the next state (hint, you can use another variable, maybe `lost4`).

Comment: This is a bit over-simplified, but doing some basic research/testing/debugging with @Frenchy 's answer as a starting point should get you some good progress.

Comment: @Alex, if you dont know the basis of logic programmation, you have to read tuto to learn `for,while, do`  loops which exist in lot of progam langage..

Comment: ok guys , thx ...